# TypeLoadException in ULS log on retract and deploy

Tags: 2010, solution-deployment

When I retract or deploy a SP2010 solution, I get the following message in the ULS:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I do not experience any problems, but still I don't like messages like that in my log. So Im wondering why this message appears, an what causes it?